# PowerQuery: Multidimensional JSON parsing

Tags: web-scraping, powerbi

With the help of many of you I have managed to create a script that scrapes grassroots fixtures. I now have a JSON with all the information scraped, but I'm completely lost on how parse it in way that allows me to build my own stats.

An example of a fixture can be seen below:

```
{
    "Temporada": "TEMPORADA 2022-2023",
    "Data": "Data: 24-09-2022,  12:30h",
    "Jornada": "Jornada 1",
    "Equip Local": {
      "Titulars": {
        "1": "SAUCEDO AVAROMA, JORDI",
        "2": "VICTOR DELGADO, GUILLEM",
        "3": "NATALI , ANDREA",
        "4": "CUENCA CEJUDO, ANDRES",
        "5": "TORRENTS SALVAT, JOFRE",
        "6": "BERNAL CASAS, MARC",
        "7": "DE MIGUEL LLAVE, CARLOS",
        "8": "AVILA MARMOL, DANIEL",
        "9": "HERNANDEZ TORRES, JUAN",
        "10": "JUNYENT CASANOVA, QUIM",
        "11": "KLUIVERT , SHANE PATRICK"
      },
      "Suplents": {
        "12": "FARRÉ MIRÓ, LANDRY CÉPHAS",
        "13": "BONFILL COLL, MAX",
        "14": "FERNANDEZ CASINO, GUILLERMO",
        "15": "SACA , LEONARD",
        "16": "ESPART FONT, XAVI",
        "17": "SYLLA DIALLO, NOUHOUN",
        "18": "GISTAU FERREÑO, ÓSCAR"
      },
      "Equip Tècnic": [
        "CARRASCO PEREA, IVAN",
        "SUAREZ GALVAN, ANTONIO",
        "BLANCO  MORENO, ARNAU",
        "PONS MARTINEZ, SIMON",
        "REINA VILLATORO, SAUL",
        "RIVAS GONZALEZ, PABLO"
      ],
      "Targetes": {
        "TORRENTS SALVAT, JOFRE": [{ "Minut": "36'", "Targeta": "groga" }]
      }
    },
    "Equip Visitant": {
      "Titulars": {
        "1": "ESTEVEZ RUBIO, MANEL",
        "2": "BORREGO CRUZADO, DAVID",
        "3": "RAFÚS AULET, JORDI",
        "4": "MEDINA LOPEZ, JOAN",
        "5": "ANGLADA GARCIA MIRANDA, GUILLEM",
        "6": "RICO CORDERO, POL",
        "7": "VILLARRASO SAMPER, NIL",
        "8": "ISERN GENE, ORIOL",
        "9": "GONZALEZ YANES, ALEX",
        "10": "RUBIRA COLAS, ADRIA",
        "11": "SOLA BURGOS, IAN"
      },
      "Suplents": {
        "12": "ROUCO BARRENA, HUGO",
        "13": "LOPEZ PASCUAL, PAU",
        "14": "LARGO SILVESTRE, PAU",
        "15": "FERNANDEZ MARTINEZ, ELLIOT",
        "16": "MORALES GOMEZ, CRISTOBAL",
        "17": "DEL MORAL RUZAFA, IKER",
        "18": "RIOS PEREZ, JOSE LUIS"
      },
      "Equip Tècnic": [
        "MENGUAL GALINDO, ANTONIO",
        "FALCES VIÑOLA, IGNACIO",
        "MONZONÍS ZORRILLA, CARLOS ",
        "MORALES SUBIRACHS, GENÍS"
      ],
      "Targetes": {
        "RUBIRA COLAS, ADRIA": [{ "Minut": "17'", "Targeta": "groga" }],
        "MORALES GOMEZ, CRISTOBAL": [{ "Minut": "79'", "Targeta": "groga" }]
      }
    },
    "Àrbitres": {
      "Àrbitres": [
        "GARCIA MUÑOZ, ORIOL",
        "ABELLO LILLO, SERGI",
        "LOPEZ RODRIGUEZ, FELIPE"
      ]
    },
    "Gols": {
      "DE MIGUEL LLAVE, CARLOS": [{ "Minut": "30'", "Tipus": "Normal" }],
      "KLUIVERT , SHANE PATRICK": [
        { "Minut": "34'", "Tipus": "Normal" },
        { "Minut": "44'", "Tipus": "Normal" }
      ],
      "CUENCA CEJUDO, ANDRES": [{ "Minut": "35'", "Tipus": "Propia" }],
      "HERNANDEZ TORRES, JUAN": [{ "Minut": "54'", "Tipus": "Normal" }],
      "BERNAL CASAS, MARC": [{ "Minut": "79'", "Tipus": "Normal" }]
    },
    "Estadi": {
      "Local": "CAMP DE FUTBOL CIUTAT ESPORTIVA JOAN GAMPER (Artificial)",
      "Visitant": "av. del Sol, s/n, Sant Joan Despí"
    },
    "Comparativa": {}
  }
```

I have looked at several videos and turorials but I cannot find a way to manage it. Can anyone guide me?

Thanks,